# Is there any major difference between innerHTML and using createTextNode to fill a span?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, createtextnode

The title is pretty clear:
Is there any major difference between `innerHTML` and `createTextNode` (used with `Append`) to fill a span with text?

Comment: What? createTextNode() is several magnitudes faster than innerHTML when appending text to a node. See http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-and-createtextnode

Comment: @devnull69 That test is specifically for appending new content multiple times (and computing HTML additions will naturally be slower). But simply adding text is very equal (innerHTML is actually a tiny bit faster): http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-and-createtextnode/2

Comment: on my machine, createTextNode in your example is still twice as fast as innerHTML (Win7 32 Enterprise, Firefox)

Comment: @devnull69 yea, actually the results fluctuate a lot, I sometimes get innerHTML slightly faster, but sometimes the other way around. Anyway, my point is that the there is likely no "major difference" as the OP asked for.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Of course. [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createTextNode) will escape any strings and show them as they are, while [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) could render html-like strings into a DOM. If you don't want that (unless you are sure the text contains no unescaped tags, e.g. when assigning a literal directly), you can use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) (or [`innerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE).

Yet I'd recommend `createTextNode`, because all browsers support it equally without any quirks.

Comment: "*...to fill a span with text*"

Comment: Yes. But *text* could contain tags etc (you never know), so I'd expect the OP to use `innerText`/`textContent` at least

Comment: @Bergi—you should update your answer to include textContent/innerText as an alternative (perhaps even preferred).

Comment: @Bergi `textContent`, and `innerText` are not cross-browser, so one would have to resort to a shim. I'd just use `innerHTML` instead.

Comment: Beware that contrary to `innerContext`, `innerText` is aware of CSS styling and will trigger a reflow. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent Do not recommend them as interchangeable.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas: Thanks for being alert, but we're talking about *setting* it

Comment: @Bergi which setting it would trigger a reflow, correct?

Comment: @adam-beck: Not immediately, no. It'll happen only when JS has stopped execution and does no more change the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Doing some research online, here's what I've found. This should cover it at a high level:

- elem.**createTextNode**(text) and elem.**textContent** = text do the exact same thing
  (src: https://javascript.info/task/createtextnode-vs-innerhtml)
- While **textContent** returns the full text contained in a node, **innerText** returns only the visible text contained in the node.
  (src: [Difference between textContent vs innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213147/difference-between-textcontent-vs-innertext))

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that certain manipulations of innerHTML remove all bound events, so using createTextNode is preferable.