# Importing content of a cpp file into my webpage

Tags: javascript

I have a C++ (.cpp) file whose contents I would like formatted on my webpage. I have it stored locally; call it `myFile.cpp`. The process I need is:

- Get contents of `myFile.cpp` stored as a JavaScript string `codeText`
- Replace all of `codeText`'s `<` characters with `&lt;` and all > characters with `&gtl;`
- Made `codeText` the inner HTML of `<pre class="prettyprint" id="blah">` (Google's code pretifier will applied inside there)

So here's my horrible attempt that isn't working:

```
        var codeText;
        var codeFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        codeFile.open("GET", "myFile.cpp", false);
        codeFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
          if(codeFile.readyState === 4)
          {
            console.log(codeFile.status);
            if(codeFile.status === 200 || codeFile.status == 0)
            {
              codeText = codeFile.responseText;
            }
          }
        }
        codeFile.send(null);
    codeText = AB_Escape(codeText);
    document.getElementById("blah").innerHTML = codeText;
```

where

```
function AB_Escape(txt)
{
    txt.replace("<","&lt;");
    txt.replace(">","&gt;");
    return txt;
}
```

This isn't working: my console reads `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

Hopefully that gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do. How can I do it correctly?

Comment: No, simply [don't use `innerHTML` but the DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13122927/1048572)! No need for manually escaping anything then.

Comment: possible duplicate of both [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572) (don't use SJAX!) and [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is executed before the element can be reached,
on the right place and/or at right time it works fine http://www.freakstyle.it/cpp/
so : put the script at bottom OR do it at Dom loaded

Answer (score 0):

Move:

```
codeText = AB_Escape(codeText);
document.getElementById("blah").innerHTML = codeText;
```

To the if-loop where you check whether status equals 200:

```
if(codeFile.status === 200 || codeFile.status == 0)
{
    codeText = codeFile.responseText;
    codeText = AB_Escape(codeText);
    document.getElementById("blah").innerHTML = codeText;
}
```

You have to process codeText after the code file is received. The file is not received yet when you call the send command.