# local storage not giving correct results

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to build post it notes. I am reading Head First Series.
I did this code.
but somehow it's no working.

```
<form action="post">
    <input id="note_text" type="text" placeholder="enter your Note">
    <input type="button" id="add_button" value="Add Note">

</form>
<ul id="postItNotesList">

    <li>This is my very first note.</li>

    <li>This is my very Second note.</li>

</ul>
```

And here is the Js

```
window.onload=init;

// Add Sticky to Page

function addStickyToPage(value) {
    var sticky = document.createElement("li");
    span.setAttribute("class", "sticky");
    document.getElementById("postItNotesList").appendChild(sticky);
}



// Create and get Sticky Note into the localStorage
function createSticky() {
    var value = document.getElementById("note_text").value;
    var key = "sticky_" + localStorage.length;
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    addStickyToPage(value);
}



function init() {

    var button = document.getElementById("add_button");
    button.onclick = createSticky;



    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var key = localStorage.key(i);
        if (key.substring(0, 6) == "sticky") {
            var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
            addStickyToPage(value);
        }
    }


}
```

So i've buld up a fiddle so that you can easily check it out
Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/top_coder_pro/hr2rgv1p/)**
Please tell me where i am doing it wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: **Uncaught ReferenceError: span is not defined**

Comment: @Ok i removed that line but still every note is blank...

Comment: _function addStickyToPage(value)_ you pass value in this function but you do nothing with it

Comment: @o how can i fix it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hr2rgv1p/1/). *Note* : first you should create DOM element and then append *text* to this element and finally append this node to you body so your code should be like this:

```
window.onload=init();

    function addStickyToPage(value) {
        var sticky = document.createElement("li");
        sticky.setAttribute("class", "sticky");
        var t = document.createTextNode(value);
        console.log(t);
        sticky.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById("postItNotesList").appendChild(sticky);
    }
```

And also `windows.onload = init()`with brackets

Thanks

Comment: thanks but Please explain this to me  var t = document.createTextNode(value);

Comment: What you just did here?

Comment: Ok So you created Text...??

Comment: _createTextNode_ it appends your text from textbox to your _sticky_ [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) you can read about this function

Comment: can i use innerHtml here??

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122760/is-there-any-major-difference-between-innerhtml-and-using-createtextnode-to-fill) good explanation about it