# Difference between textContent vs innerText

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `textContent` and `innerText` in JavaScript?

Can I use `textContent` as follows:

```
var logo$ = document.getElementsByClassName('logo')[0];
logo$.textContent = "Example";
```

Comment: @Pointy what is the one that all browsers support?

Comment: A [good blog post](http://www.kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/) about it

Comment: There isn't one. You have to include code to check which exists and then use that one.

Comment: @Pointy please refer to the blog post I pointed to. Your statement is incorrect, there is a difference.

Comment: jQuery's `.text()` method is your friend here: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: @Tyblitz yes you're right, but the reason that sites use `innerText` is because *there's no choice* on older IE versions.

Comment: `innerText` and `textContent` are decidedly not the same. White-space occurences in node content will cause the two properties yield different content, and so will occurences of `br` elements and other block-level rendered descendants.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [innerText vs innerHTML vs label vs text vs textContent vs outerText](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24427621/90527)

Comment: It appears to me that none of the answers has fully addressed whether there is any difference in the setters in the case of an HTMLElement, where both are present. By comparing the MDN description of the setters for [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and for [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) it seems not. But maybe somebody has more insight?

Comment: I figured out in the meantime, that using `innerText` as setter turns `\n` into `<br>`. I was aware of the other direction in the getter, but I had not expected that markup is produced when setting text. For `textContent` this is of course not the case.

Answer (score 480):

The key differences between `innerText` and `textContent` are outlined very well in [Kelly Norton's blogpost: innerText vs. textContent](http://www.kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/). Below you can find a summary:

1. `innerText` was non-standard, `textContent` was standardized earlier.
2. `innerText` returns the **visible** text contained in a node, while `textContent` returns the **full** text. For example, on the following HTML `<span>Hello <span style="display: none;">World</span></span>`, `innerText` will return 'Hello', while `textContent` will return 'Hello World'. For a more complete list of differences, see the table at http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/ (further reading at ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox/1359822#1359822)).
3. As a result, `innerText` is much more performance-heavy: it requires layout information to return the result.
4. [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) is defined only for `HTMLElement` objects, while [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is defined for all `Node` objects.

Be sure to also have a look at the informative comments below this answer.

`textContent` was unavailable in IE8-, and a bare-metal polyfill would have looked like a recursive function using `nodeValue` on all `childNodes` of the specified node:

```
function textContent(rootNode) {
  if ('textContent' in document.createTextNode(''))
    return rootNode.textContent;

  var childNodes = rootNode.childNodes,
      len = childNodes.length,
      result = '';
  
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (childNodes[i].nodeType === 3)
      result += childNodes[i].nodeValue;
    else if (childNodes[i].nodeType === 1) 
      result += textContent(childNodes[i]);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting: `innerText` will turn `<br>` elements into newline characters, while `textContent` will just ignore them. So 2 words with only a `<br>` element between them (and no spaces) will be concatenated when using `textContent`

Comment: Then is there any difference when the setter is used? Like `elem.textContent = 'foobar'` v.s. `elem.innerText = 'foobar'`

Comment: Another difference in behavior between `innerText` and `textContent`: If you change the `text-transform` of an element by CSS, it will affect the result of 'innerText', but not the result of `textContent`.

For example:  `innerText` of 
`<div style="text-transform: uppercase;">Hello World</div>`
will be "HELLO WORLD", while `textContent` will be "Hello World".

Comment: Regarding to point "3" (performance). I did a quick test and I don't see that it's true. `let allElements = [...document.getElementsByTagName('*')];
t1 = performance.now();
for(let i=0; i<allElements.length; i++){
    txt = allElements[i].innerText;
}
t2 = performance.now();
console.log('innerText', t2-t1);
for(let i=0; i<allElements.length; i++){
    txt = allElements[i].textContent;
}
t3 = performance.now();
console.log('textContent', t3-t2);` Execute it in console and see. In some cases (on this site, for example) textContent is a little better, on mail.google.com - vice versa.

Comment: @ShimonS *innerText is much more performance-heavy* is true, but is to be taken relatively: if `innerText` is 100x slower than `textContent` on avg, and `textContent` takes 1/1000 of a millisecond per op, 1/10th of a millisecond will still *feel* fast to humans. Furthermore a meaningful comparison between the 2 can only be one where the element contains a lot of hidden stuff like `<script>` or `style="display: none;"` children

Comment: @Kobi, I don't see this is true, https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-b86gal?file=index.html

Comment: If you're creating a search function within the DOM, `textContent` is infinitely better.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72874515/is-there-any-way-to-optimize-my-client-side-search-function

Comment: @Normal Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I've edited your example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hv6fwn?file=index.js

. Check the console output after clicking the button.

Comment: @Kobi, yep, now I see

Answer (score 61):

`textContent` is the only one available for text nodes:

```js
var text = document.createTextNode('text');

console.log(text.innerText);    //  undefined
console.log(text.textContent);  //  text
```

In element nodes, `innerText` evaluates `<br>` elements, while `textContent` evaluates control characters:

```js
var span = document.querySelector('span');
span.innerHTML = "1<br>2<br>3<br>4\n5\n6\n7\n8";
console.log(span.innerText); // breaks in first half
console.log(span.textContent); // breaks in second half
```

```html
<span></span>
```

`span.innerText` gives:

```
1
2
3
4 5 6 7 8
```

`span.textContent` gives:

```
1234
5
6
7
8
```

Strings with control characters (e. g. line feeds) are not available with `textContent`, if the content was set with `innerText`. The other way (set control characters with `textContent`), all characters are returned both with `innerText` and `textContent`:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerText = "x\ny";
console.log(div.textContent);  //  xy
```

Answer (score 47):

For those who googled this question and arrived here. I feel the most clear answer to this question is in MDN document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent.

You can forgot all the points that may confuse you but remember 2 things:

1. When you are trying to alter the text, `textContent` is usually the property you are looking for.
2. When you are trying to grab text from some element, `innerText` approximates the text the user would get if they highlighted the contents of the element with the cursor and then copied to the clipboard. And `textContent` gives you everything, visible or hidden, including `<script>` and `<style>` elements.

Comment: "Moreover, since innerText takes CSS styles into account, reading the value of innerText triggers a reflow to ensure up-to-date computed styles. (Reflows can be computationally expensive, and thus should be avoided when possible.)"

"Reflow happens when a browser must process and draw part or all of a webpage again, such as after an update on an interactive site."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Reflow

innerText <-> ReFlow relationship.

Those MDN articles is more explanatory than other answers.

Comment: @Northern from the MDN link you provided I couldn't determine any difference in the setters, but only in the getters. At least when both are present. Would you agree?

Answer (score 28):

Both [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) & [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) are standardized as of 2016. All `Node` objects (including pure text nodes) have `textContent`, but only `HTMLElement` objects have `innerText`.

While `textContent` works with most browsers, it does not work on IE8 or earlier. Use this polyfill for it to work on IE8 only. This polyfill will not work with IE7 or earlier.

```
if (Object.defineProperty 
  && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor 
  && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "textContent") 
  && !Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "textContent").get) {
  (function() {
    var innerText = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, "innerText");
    Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "textContent",
     {
       get: function() {
         return innerText.get.call(this);
       },
       set: function(s) {
         return innerText.set.call(this, s);
       }
     }
   );
  })();
}
```

The `Object.defineProperty` method is availabe in IE9 or up, however it is available in IE8 for DOM objects only.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: Here's the spec for it, too: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html

Also the (very old) browser support table (http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-dom#dom3core) suggests, that it's supported for IE9+, so for IE8 and older, `innerText` is your friend.

Comment: Actually, it's a better idea to either not support ie8 or use the polyfill. I posted the polyfill in my post

Comment: How can that polyfill work in IE8 when it didn't support `Object.defineProperty()`?

Comment: Just took a look at the MDN documentation. It says this  `In Internet Explorer 8 only on DOM objects and with some non-standard behaviors.`

Comment: why don't you update your answer? https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute

Comment: Here is a quote from MDN about innerText - "This feature was originally introduced by Internet Explorer, and was formally specified in the HTML standard in 2016 after being adopted by all major browser vendors."

Answer (score 8):

textContent is supported by most browsers.  It is not supported by ie8 or earlier, but a polyfill can be used for this

> The textContent property sets or returns the textual content of the specified node, and all its descendants.

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_textcontent.asp

Answer (score 7):

Aside from all the differences that were named in the other answers, here is another one which I discovered only recently:

Even though the `innerText` property is said to've been standardised since 2016, it exhibits differences between browsers: Mozilla ignores U+200E and U+200F characters ("lrm" and "rlm") in `innerText`, while Chrome does not.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('test').textContent.length);
console.log(document.getElementById('test').innerText.length);
```

```html
<div id="test">[&#x200E;]</div>
```

Firefox reports 3 and 2, Chrome reports 3 and 3.

Not sure yet if this is a bug (and if so, in which browser) or just one of those quirky incompatibilities which we have to live with.

Comment: Wow. Amazingly found!!

Answer (score 5):

`textContent` returns full text and does not care about visibility, while `innerText` does.

```
<p id="source">
    <style>#source { color: red; }</style>
    Text with breaking<br>point.
    <span style="display:none">HIDDEN TEXT</span>
</p>
```

Output of `textContent`:

```
#source { color: red; } Text with breakingpoint. HIDDEN TEXT
```

Output of `innerText` ( note how `innerText` is aware of tags like `<br>`, and ignores hidden element ):

```
Text with breaking point.
```

Comment: In IE11, the behavior of innerText is the same as the one of textContent.

Answer (score 1):

Another useful behavior of `innerText` compared to `textContent` is that newline characters and multiple spaces next to each other will be displayed as one space only, which can be easier to compare a string.

But depending on what you want, `firstChild.nodeValue` may be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('h1').innerText/innerHTML/textContent
```

`.querySelector('h1').innerText` - gives us text inside. It sensitive to what is currently being displayed or staff that's being hidden is ignored.

`.querySelector('h1').textContent` - it's like `innerText` but it does not care about what is being displayed or what's actually showing to user. It will show all.

`.querySelector('h1').innerHTML` = `<i>sdsd</i>` Will work* - retrieves full contents, including the tag names.

Comment: Is there any innertextContent?

Comment: @m4n0 no, I've corrected the answer

Answer (score -3):

innerHTML will execute even the HTML tags which might be dangerous causing any kind of client-side injection attack like DOM based XSS.
Here is the code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var source = "Hello " + decodeURIComponent("<h1>Text inside gets executed as h1 tag HTML is evaluated</h1>");  //Source
            var divElement = document.createElement("div");
            divElement.innerHTML = source;  //Sink
            document.body.appendChild(divElement);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you use .textContent, it will not evaluate the HTML tags and print it as String.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var source = "Hello " + decodeURIComponent("<h1>Text inside will not get executed as HTML</h1>");  //Source
            var divElement = document.createElement("div");
            divElement.textContent = source;  //Sink
            document.body.appendChild(divElement);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Reference: https://www.scip.ch/en/?labs.20171214

Comment: The question did not mention `innerHTML`. The answer did not mention `innerText`.