# How to ignore HTML tags in innerHTML attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, escaping

I'm making a messenger and my messages don't ignore HTML tags because I simply past a text from input in innerHTML of message. My code:

```
function Message(sender) {
    ...
    this["text"] = "";
    ...
    this.addText = function (text) {
        this["text"] = text;
    };
    ...
};
```

And here I display it:

```
...
var chatMessageText = document.createElement("p");
chatMessageText.innerHTML = message["text"];
...
```

What can I do for ignoring HTML tags in message["text"]?

Comment: You are using a property specifically designed to hold HTML. Why do you want to _ignore_ HTML? Shouldn't you be using a text node and just let users type HTML?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I see, I have never met before with using text nodes and so it's the first meeting:) Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. As user, I feel terribly frustrated when my forum comment or whatever gets truncated just because I type some angle bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update [`Node#innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) property(or [`Node#textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property).

```
chatMessageText.innerText = message["text"];
```

---

Check the difference of both here : [innerText vs textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText)

Refer :  [Difference between text content vs inner text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213147/difference-between-text-content-vs-inner-text)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this attribute. So simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The point of `innerHTML` is that you give it HTML and it interprets it as HTML.

You could escape all the special characters, but the easier solution is to *not use `innerHTML`*.

```
var chatMessagePara = document.createElement("p");
var chatMessageText = document.createTextNode(message["text"]);
chatMessagePara.appendChild(chatMessageText)
```

Comment: Thank you! I really forgot about TextNodes.