# How to retrieve the Text of an element along with <br> as text not as a new Line

Tags: java, selenium, getattribute

[image: Outlined problem]

In the image above as we can see there's a `<\br>` in the text. Now in the assert statement, I have to verify it against the option I select which has a 'whitespace' but not `<\br>` which returns the text after it to a new line.

So what I am trying to do here is I want to retrieve the value of the `<div>` including the `<\br>` as 'text' so that I can retrieve the whole text and replace `<\br>` with a 'space' and then verify against the expected text.

I tried-`<br>`

1. `getAttribute("textContent")`:

```java
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[contains(@class,'v-label')])).getAttribute("textContent");
```

which retrieves text without `<\br>` like - `CIABC-Idq BLA HLA N1 Dd/Coind(BLen AccBLA HLA)`

2. `getAttribute("innerText")`:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[contains(@class,'v-label')])).getAttribute("innerText");
```

which retrieves text with returning to the new line like - 
`CIABC-Idq BLA HLA N1 Dd/Coind
(BLen AccBLA HLA)`

**Expected**:

1. I would either need to retrieve the text with a space between the `CIABC-Idq BLA HLA N1 Dd/Coind` and `(BLen AccBLA HLA)`

Or

2. The Whole Text along with `<\br>` between the `CIABC-Idq BLA HLA N1 Dd/Coind` and `(BLen AccBLA HLA)` so I could replace the characters `<\br>` with a whitespace and then assert the string with expected value.

**HTML CODE SNIPPET:**

```html
<div class="v-slot">
    <div class="v-label v-widget v-label-undef-w">
        CIABC-Idq BLA HLA N1 Dd/Coind
        <br>
        (BLen AccBLA HLA)
    </div>
</div>
```

could someone help?

Comment: Can you try using `getAttribute("innerHTML")` instead?

Comment: That was it! it worked!

Comment: Posted @MattClark comment as an answer to resolve the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`textContent` will evaluate control characters and `innerText` will evaluate `<br>` tags, thus returning text only. (see [difference between textContent vs innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49003197/5037430))

Instead, you can get the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[contains(@class,'v-label')])).getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

> The Element property innerHTML gets or sets the HTML or XML markup contained within the element.

`innerHTML` will preserve the markup.