# How do you get the inner text inside these classes with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have

```
<div class="ce">
  <div class="lotB">9</div>
  <div class="lotB">3</div>
  <div class="lotB">28</div> == $0
</div>
```

I'm trying to get these three numbers `9, 3, 28` but I can't get this to work :s

Already tried several different things and I also read about innerText and tried to get it work by going through the class `ce` like that

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ce");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var numbers = x[i].innerText;
  alert(numbers);
}
```

But also this didn't give me anything : /

How do you get this inner text of each these classes, so I got the numbers `9, 3, 28`?

Comment: You're selecting the wrong class.

Comment: If you aren't getting an alert at all then your code is running before your elements exist, eg your code is in head while the body hasn't been parsed yet.

Comment: Thank you all for help it works very good now and very nice to know different ways of getting this work! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to target all the `div` inside the class. Change the selector to:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".ce > div");
```

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".ce > div");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var numbers = x[i].innerText;
  alert(numbers);
}
```

```html
<div class="ce">
  <div class="lotB">9</div>
  <div class="lotB">3</div>
  <div class="lotB">28</div> == $0
</div>
```

Comment: Why not `.lotB` directly?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("lotB")` as `lotB` has that values. Also note that if you want to do any arithmetic operations on that values you need to use `parseInt(numbers)` to get its numeric representation.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("lotB");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var numbers = x[i].innerText;
  alert(numbers);
}
```

```html
<div class="ce">
  <div class="lotB">9</div>
  <div class="lotB">3</div>
  <div class="lotB">28</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("lotB");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var numbers = x[i].textContent;
  alert(numbers);
}
```

```html
<div class="ce">
  <div class="lotB">9</div>
  <div class="lotB">3</div>
  <div class="lotB">28</div> == $0
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbers = x[i].textContent;
```

Rather than using `InnerHtml` use `textContent`

[Difference between textContent vs innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213147/difference-between-textcontent-vs-innertext)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName("lotB")].forEach(e=>console.log(e.innerText));
```

```html
<div class="ce">
  <div class="lotB">9</div>
  <div class="lotB">3</div>
  <div class="lotB">28</div> == $0
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

give each elements the same class

```
  <div class="ce">
   <div class="lotB">9</div>
   <div class="lotB">3</div>
   <div class="lotB">28</div> == $0
  </div>
```

the key here is that it says "get element**s**" and therefore it can handle multiple classes that are the same

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("lotB");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var numbers = x[i].innerHtml;
  alert(numbers);
}
```

i use .innerHtml here