# Going to the next line while printing

Tags: javascript

```js
var i = 0;
var string = "Size: test ";
var speed = 50;

function printtext() {

  if (i < string.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += string.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(printtext, speed);
  }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="printtext()">Click me</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

I am trying to seperate "Size:" and "test". I would like "test" to be on the next line (under) so that when my button is clicked, it displays (like a typewriter) a list of information.

Conclusion: I'm just trying to find a way to go to the next line like some sort of \n.

Thank you,

Nathan

Comment: You don't have to add `(solved)` to the question title. Marking an answer is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use a `<pre>` element as the target, and `\n`s for linebreaks.

That way, you can even avoid the use of `.innerHTML` and use `.textContent` or `.innerText` instead ([which one you like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35213147/8376184)).

You could also apply some CSS to restore the default font:

```js
var i = 0;
var string = "Size:\ntest ";
var speed = 50;

function printtext() {

  if (i < string.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerText += string.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(printtext, speed);
  }

}
```

```css
pre{
  font: initial
}
```

```html
<button onclick="printtext()">Click me</button>
<pre id="demo"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you FZs, it looks like I was using <p> and not <pre>. I appreciate the fast replies !

Answer (score 2):

Since the only thing that separates `Size:` and `test` strings is a whitespace, you can simply check if `string.charAt(i)` is a whitespace character. If it is, then you simply print a `<br />` tag instead of the whitespace character itself.

```js
var i = 0;
var string = "Size: test "; 
var speed = 50;

function printtext() {

  if (i < string.length) {
    var character = string.charAt(i);
    if (character === ' ') {
      character = '<br />';
    }
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += character;
    i++;
    setTimeout(printtext, speed);
  }

}

printtext();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with little `if` statement, like you can say if `string.charAt(i) === " ")`  put `<br>` to get next line

**Code ↓↓**

```js
var i = 0;
var string = "Size: test ";
var speed = 50;

function printtext() {

  if (i < string.length) {
     if(string.charAt(i) === " "){
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "<br>";
     }
     else 
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += string.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(printtext, speed);
  }

}
```

```html
<button onclick="printtext()">Click me</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```