# How to rewrite text of an option in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, select

I've encountered one issue: I don't know how to rewrite the (inner)text of an option in a select.

My goal would be something like that:

```html
<select id="example-dropdown">
     <option id="option-id" value="example-option">Example</option>
</select>

<button id="change-option-text-btn" onclick="document.querySelector('#option-id').innerText = 'Example 2'">Click Me</button>
```

I know this is a possible duplicate, but all of the answers I found are not working for me (I also found some jQuery ones, I don't know if they don't work neither), such as:

```
document.querySelector("#example-dropdown").options[0].text = "Example 2"
```

Didn't encounter any error messages.

Edit: Ok, I'm sorry, I didn't say it: this is just an example code, the onclick is there just for saving time

Comment: That's because in plain JS, it's `textContent = ...`, not `.text = ...`, and in jQuery it's `.text("...")`, also not `.text = ...`. Having said that, you probably also want to stop using that legacy `onclick` handler and instead do things properly by having your .js in a file, loaded using a `<script src="..." async defer>` element (with those extra attributes), in which you first find your button, then attach an event listener.

Comment: `querySelector('#example-option option')`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks so much! For the onlick, I don't use it in my original code, it's just for making the example code smaller. In the original code, I have it in an external file with classic addEventListener() method. Gonna try your solution.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Actually, [the `option` element has a `text` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement) that sets the text of the option, in addition to the `textContent` property... which does the same thing.

Comment: Actually, I tried to change the option's text by selecting it by id and innerText, but it didn't work. I wrote it wrong in the question. Gonna edit it

Comment: @PythonisFine not quite. [The `.text` property does not do the same thing as `textContent`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#htmloptionelement), and is typically best avoided because of that silent rewrite. Sticking to the same attribute that every other HTML element uses is a good habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a couple of issues with your current code and I will point them out briefly here.

- First of all, it is better to stick with [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) solution in your code and handle all of the logic inside a `<script>` or JS file instead of handling them in the HTML itself. So for this, I just removed the `onclick` handler from the HTML and moved it in the JS section and tried to access the element and adding event to it by [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) approach.
- Your first snippet should work as expected if you select the right element in the query selector, so you can change the selector to `document.querySelector('#example-dropdown option[value=example-option]')`, but due to the `innerText` drawbacks *(Which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35213639/11908502))* it is better to not use it at all for changing the inner text of elements.
- If you do not want to use `innerText` for its drawbacks, to change the content of the HTML tag you can use the [`innerHTML`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiz7raVkMvsAhXRCewKHWFaBoEQFjAAegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FElement%2FinnerHTML&usg=AOvVaw2wepyL8Jm23--FAliFQkOZ) or [`textContent`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjf3OuMkMvsAhUGC-wKHaESDisQFjAAegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FNode%2FtextContent&usg=AOvVaw3X4dFyiw2r6F89WvDfvIDh) property. Which is in your case since you are only trying to change the text of the option alone you need to use `textContent`.

Your final code should be something like this:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#change-option-text-btn');
const select = document.querySelector('#example-dropdown');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  select.options[0].textContent = 'Example 2'
});
```

```html
<select id="example-dropdown">
  <option value="example-option">Example</option>
</select>

<button id="change-option-text-btn">Click Me</button>
```

---

Also, in your particular case since you are trying to change the inner text of the select option there is one more option for you as you tried earlier is to use `text` property which works the same as `textContent` and it is only available for [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement)s.

<sup>So, `document.querySelector("#example-dropdown").options[0].text` should do the work for you.</sup>

And it will be like this:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#change-option-text-btn');
const select = document.querySelector('#example-dropdown');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  select.options[0].text = 'Example 2'
});
```

```html
<select id="example-dropdown">
  <option value="example-option">Example</option>
</select>

<button id="change-option-text-btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I know about the html mashup, but in the original code I have it all in an external JS file similar to the code you wrote, I put it all into HTML just because of time saving.

Comment: The use of `.text` in OP's question was just wondering about jquery (yes, it's wrong for jquery). In code for "My goal would be something like" they use `.innerText = 'Example 2'` which would work fine _if_ the right element was selected. You don't "_**need**_" to use `textContent`. Also, there's no sign of OP using `.innerHTML` in the whole edit history for the question.

Comment: @StephenP As you might know better than me, the `innerText` is not a standard property to use and due to its drawbacks, it is better to avoid using it. So I suggest other available standard approaches. But for the record, I will add these notes to the answer as well. Thank you.

Comment: [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) is an [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) property while [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is part of the [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node) interface. They are both standard interfaces at different abstraction levels. Various APIs return either/or so it's good to know both textContent and innerText.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I didn't know about the negatives of innerText