# Is it better to set innerText to null or ' '?

Tags: javascript, html, null, innertext

I want to empty the innerText of an element. Wondering if it's better practice to set the innerText to `null` or `''`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use `textContent`, not `innerText`.

Comment: It's a string, so you should set it to an empty string.

Answer (score 4):

- <del>Use `textContent`, not `innerText`.</del>

  - <del>`innerText` is non-standard and originates with Internet Explorer and has some ill-defined behaviour, though all major browsers support it.</del>
  - <del>`textContent` is standard and is more rigidly defined, hence why it should be preferred.</del>

[The IDL for DOM's `textContent`](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/idl-definitions.html) describes it as a non-nullable `DOMString`, so any `null` JavaScript `string` value will be converted to an empty-string by the browser.

So it doesn't matter.

Comment: It's standard since 2016, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213147/difference-between-textcontent-vs-innertext

Comment: @Barmar Wow, TIL! Thank you. Here's the spec reference: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute - though I can only find it on WHATWG rather than in the W3C's IDL.

Comment: But there are indeed a number of differences, as summarized in the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

It should do the same thing because it probably checks internally for a null argument and turns it into an empty string, but using `''` would be better (since it would be better understood what you're trying to do with that).

Comment: Right, I just tried setting to `null`, then retrieving it returned `''`