# I want to log to console text from all elements using same class

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbyclassname

Can somebody please help me why I have in console 2 times undefined? And how can I fix this? T

```js
const intro = document.querySelectorAll('.intro');

for (i = 0; i < intro.length; i++) {
  console.log(intro[i].innerContent);
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">The DOM is very useful.</div>
<div class="intro">This example demonstrates the method.</div>
```

Comment: There's no attribute called `innerContent`. Use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), or [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText). They [do have differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213147/difference-between-textcontent-vs-innertext).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) property (possibly [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)). There is also a [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property, but that is probably not what you want because it gets non-human-readable text content including the contents of style and script tags.

```js
const intro = document.querySelectorAll('.intro');
for (i = 0; i < intro.length; i++) {
  console.log(intro[i].innerText);
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">The DOM is very useful.</div>
<div class="intro">This example demonstrates the method.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for correction. I have one more question:

If I want use method .getElementsByClassName() instead and than print innerText from every element that uses class intro. How it would be?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The `getElementsByClassName()` function would work very similarly: `document.getElementsByClassName('intro')`, just note that you do not include the dot before the class name (i.e. you want `'intro'` not `'.intro'`)

Answer (score 0):

Because no property called `innerContent` exists for html elements, and attempting to access properties that don't exist always returns `undefined` in Javascript. You're probably looking for [.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).