# How to get a list of values from a specific CSS Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nodelist

I want to retrieve at once a list of values from a spcific CSS selector.

I want to extract the text in `<strong>` only. I am using :

```
document.querySelectorAll("p > strong")
```

But the I got a Node list...

```
NodeList(101) [strong, strong, strong, strong, strong, strong, strong, strong, strong,...]
```

I am targeting the innerText like :

```
document.querySelectorAll("p > strong")[1].innerText
```

How can I extract all the targeted text values in a list at once ?

Comment: Tagged [tag:jquery] so:  `$("p>strong").map((i,e) => $(e).text()).toArray()`  (not provied as an answer as it doesn't look like you *actually* want jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to turn it into an array and then use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to get what you need.

```js
var array = [...document.querySelectorAll("p > strong")].map(a=>a.innerText);

console.log(array);
```

```html
<p><strong>I</strong></p>
<p><strong>heart</strong></p>
<p><strong>To</strong></p>
<p><strong>Fart</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works if you loop over the nodeList you have

I use textContent though - same thing but more standard

```js
const strong = document.querySelectorAll("p > strong")
const texts = []
for (let i = 0; i< strong.length;i++) texts.push(strong[i].textContent)
console.log(texts)
```

```html
<p>Here is some <strong>text</strong> and some <strong>more text</strong></p>
```

Alternatively but slower (if that matters) map the nodelist after casting to array using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const texts = [...document.querySelectorAll("p > strong")]
  .map(({textContent}) => textContent)
console.log(texts)
```

```html
<p>Here is some <strong>text</strong> and some <strong>more text</strong></p>
```

jQuery if you need

```js
const texts = $("p strong").map((_,e) => e.textContent).get();
console.log(texts)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Here is some <strong>text</strong> and some <strong>more text</strong></p>
```

Comment: `textContent` and `innerText` are not the same, nor is one *more standard* than another. `innerText` only shows rendered text whereas `textContent` would show the CSS or Javascript code of a `<style>` or `<script>` within the target element. Might be the same in this case, but probably not a good idea to make that assumption.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213147/difference-between-textcontent-vs-innertext

Comment: Being standardized earlier doesn't make it "more standard."