# Simple appearing animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just make a very very simple animation:

```css
p {
  animation: appear 1s linear 1;
  font-family:monospace;
}

@keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Thank you for any helps!</p>
```

It works, but I am just thinking is it possible to make the first letter appear first, after the first letter appearing, then the second, and finally the last letter (now the whole content of `p` will appear at the same time)

Does CSS have any selectors to select every characters in the element and is it possible to achieve the effect use CSS only?

I only know `first-letter` and `last-letter` selector in css, but not sure if css has selector for every letters

If not only with CSS, I would be also Ok with JS solution?

Appreciate for any helps provided~

Comment: Splitting.js is great for this - it automatically breaks blocks of text into lines, words or single characters, and it works wonderfully with CSS transitions. https://splitting.js.org/

Comment: @SigurdMazanti, interesting, maybe consider writing an answer for it? Because I never hear that before and I mostly written in vanilla js

Comment: If you use a mono space font you can do it in pure CSS. Otherwise you’ll need to put each character in its own element.

Comment: @AHaworth, how does the font make the difference??? I changed it in my code  snnipet above, seems no difference?

Comment: You could use [scss for](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for) loop to populate it but that would be a terrible solution. It would work nicely when you have fixed size text (also requires a separated tag for each letter)

Comment: If you use a monospace font you can expand the width of the containing p element in a CSS animation one ch step at a time. Is it acceptable to have a monospace font for your application?

Comment: @AHaworth, I will be OK with that font-family

Comment: @AHaworth, I just try to use the way you have, but seems not working, do you mind share an working example or writting an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vanilla JS approach. First we extract the text, empty the element, then rebuild it one character at a time.

```js
let p = document.querySelector('.anim');
// store value
let t = p.innerText.split(''),
  counter = 0
p.innerHTML = '';

let inter = setInterval(() => {
  if (counter == t.length) clearInterval(inter)
  else p.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<span>${t[counter++]}</span>`);
}, 100)
```

```css
p.anim span {
  animation: appear 1s linear 1;
}

@keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class='anim'>Thank you for any helps!</p>
```

Comment: Thanks so much !  A very nice answer. Just wonder will be using `textContent` better than `innerText`? I know it is a little bit off-topic and easy to search, but just curious on your opinion?

Comment: They are mostly interchangeable -- though you can see the differences here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35213639/1772933

Comment: `counter == t.length ? clearInterval(inter) : p.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 
  <span>${t[counter++]}</span> );` will  be shorter, but anyways thanks.  I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If a JS-based solution is acceptable, then you can easily achieve this using a combination of DOM manipulation (wrapping each non-space character in a `<span>` element), and then sequentially toggling a class that runs the animation.

The sequential part can be achieved by simply looping through the generated `<span>` element, and then awaiting for a promise to be resolved.

In your question it is not clear how you want to be a delay to be calculated: I simply assume you want an arbitrary/customizable delay. In this case, a simple promise-based `sleep` function can get the job done:

```js
function sleep(ms = 0) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
}

async function fadeInCharacters(el) {
  // NOTE: Use a custom data- attribute to ensure we only target the <span> elements we generate
  el.innerHTML = el.textContent.replace(/([^\s])/g, '<span data-animate>$1</span>');
  for (const span of el.querySelectorAll('span[data-animate]')) {
    span.classList.add('animate');
    await sleep(100);
  }
}

fadeInCharacters(document.querySelector('p'));
```

```css
.animate {
  animation: appear 1s ease-in-out 1 forwards;
}

span {
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Thank you for any help!</p>
```

If you want to **wait for each character before fading in the next**, then change the await function into something that hooks into the `animationend` event, although I am inclined to believe this is not what you intend. Just putting it out here for the sake of completeness:

```js
function onAnimationEnd(el) {
  return new Promise(r => el.addEventListener('animationend', () => r()));
}

async function fadeInCharacters(el) {
  // NOTE: Use a custom data- attribute to ensure we only target the <span> elements we generate
  el.innerHTML = el.textContent.replace(/([^\s])/g, '<span data-animate>$1</span>');
  for (const span of el.querySelectorAll('span[data-animate]')) {
    span.classList.add('animate');
    await onAnimationEnd(span);
  }
}

fadeInCharacters(document.querySelector('p'));
```

```css
.animate {
  animation: appear 1s ease-in-out 1 forwards;
}

span {
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Thank you for any help!</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing me another idea by using async function. Curious what does the `replace(/([^\s])/g, '<span data-animate>$1</span>')` does and what is the regular expression? The white space?