# Javascript new line built string?

Tags: javascript, string, newline

I'm building a string in JavaScript FE like you can see below, my attempt is to print some data in different rows.
In my JavaScript I build the string the use `getElement()` and `textContent` to attach the string at the paragraph.

I've tried `<br>` `<br/>` `\n` `<\r`, all with no results.

```
var str;
str+="text" + data[0];
  str+= //Here need new line
str+="text" + data[1];

var p=document.getElementById("paragraph");
p.textContent = str;
```

Comment: In html use `<br />` tag for a visual new line. For a file on filesystem "\n" works generally.

Answer (score 1):

A couple options you have are:

1. put a `<br/>` in the string and set the `p.innerHTML = str` instead of setting textContent

```js
let myEl = document.getElementById('myelement');
let data = 'test 1';
data += '<br/>';
data += 'test 2';

myEl.innerHTML = data;
```

```html
<div id="myelement"></div>
```

OR

2. put a `\n` character in the string and then use a `white-space: pre` in the CSS of your element

```js
let myEl = document.getElementById('myelement');
let data = 'test 1';
data += '\n';
data += 'test 2';

myEl.textContent = data;
```

```css
#myelement {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="myelement"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and then use `innerText` rather than `textContent` as they [are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213147/difference-between-textcontent-vs-innertext).

```js
const arr = ['Bob', 'Jane'];

const str = `
  text: ${arr[0]}
  text: ${arr[1]}
`;

document.body.innerText = str;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a string that can be displayed/downloaded as a file and displayed in html at the same time, i would use `\n` and `innerText` :

```
var str;
str+="text" + data[0];
  str+= '\n';
str+="text" + data[1];

var p=document.getElementById("paragraph");
p.innerText = str;
```

the `\n` will be replaced by `<br/>`  automatically when using innerText, and you wont need to style it with `whitespace`, and you could use the resulting string, to perhaps start a file download