# Extract content inside a body tag as json using javascript HTML DOM in Flutter

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, dom

i am trying to figure out how to extract the json data from the following:

**HTML RESPONSE**

```
<html><body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
{'name':'john doe'}
</body></html>
```

**I have Tried**

`document.body.innerHTML` which returns `null`

**and**

`document.body.outerHTML`  which returns

```
<body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{'name:'john doe'}</body>
```

**What i want as a string**

`{'name':'john doe'}`

> Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your `<pre>` tag does not have closing tag.

Comment: its just an example the full document does have closing tags

Answer (score 2):

try this,

in your html

```
<html><body>
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
{"name":"john doe"} </pre>
</body></html>
```

in your js

```
const pre = document.querySelector('pre')
console.log(pre.innerText) // you can also use pre.textContent
```

checkout Difference between textContent vs innerText:
[Difference between textContent vs innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213147/difference-between-textcontent-vs-innertext)

Comment: Hey , so im using flutter framework and ```jsonDecode(pre.innerTEXT)``` is not returning a map .

Comment: did you mean `pre.innerText`? 
Your json data must have double quotes. `{"name":"john doe"}`

Comment: yeah pre.innerText but when i print it it gives "{"\name":"\John Does"}"

Comment: if i use jsonDecode("{"\name":"\John Does"}"), i get a string in response and not a MAP

Comment: since it's an issue of inter programming i tried ```jsonDecode("{jsonDecode(pre.innerText)}")``` . it's working now