# Calling a function from an external JavaScript file in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, stackblitz

I'm learning HTML and practicing in the StackBlitz in-browser IDE. I'm trying to use a  element's `onclick` to change the text of a `<p>` element, but nothing's happening when I click the button.

Code in the `index.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <p id="words">Starting Text</p>
    <button onclick="change()">Change Words</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

Code in the `script.js` file:

```javascript
function change() {
  document.getElementById("words").innerText = 'Words Have Been Changed';
}
```

`index.html` and `script.js` are both in the root folder in the StackBlitz project directory.

I don't know if there's an obvious syntax blunder I'm missing, or if there's something I don't understand about the StackBlitz IDE, or something else. I tried assigning the `alert()` function to `onclick`, as well as custom functions defined in the HTML, and those all worked. It's just when the assigned function is from the script.js file that nothing happens.

Comment: Scripts imported as modules will not place global symbols in the browser global context (`window`), which is required for symbols referenced in HTML attribute values as in your case. Also, the name "change" is kind-of dangerous; global symbols (`window` properties) can collide with built-in read-only property names. The right thing to do is to bind event handlers in your JavaScript and not in your HTML.

Comment: As @Pointy, said just removed the `type="module"` in your script. Your function will work after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either remove `type="module"` since a module's scope is private or add `Object.assign(window, {change})` to your `script.js`. `Object.assign()` is used to assign several functions at once, could be useful later.

```html
<script type="module">
function change() {
  document.getElementById("words").innerText = 'Words Have Been Changed';
}
Object.assign(window, {change});
</script>
<p id="words">Starting Text</p>
<button onclick="change()">Change Words</button>
```

But better use `addEventListener`...

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just assign the event listener in the script, rather than making a global function and using HTML assignment of behavior?

Comment: @HereticMonkey, yes, better, but the question was why it doesn't work...

Comment: Great, thanks, taking out the module type worked! So to use addEventListener() I would add something like the following to script.js?

`const btn = document.getElementById("button1");
btn.addEventListener("click",change);`

Comment: @EricByrd yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript code is correct:

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById("words").innerText = 'Words Have Been Changed';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <p id="words">Starting Text</p>
    <button onclick="change()">Change Words</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

so referring the script is problematic. Remove the `type="module"` part

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea but it should probably work like this:

```js
const changeEl = document.getElementById('wordsDiv');
const buttonEl = document.querySelector("button");

buttonEl.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  changeEl.textContent = 'words have been change';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wordsDiv">Starting Text</div>
    <button></button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You may wanna go with "textContent" instead of "innerText" but that's maybe just my preference, I dunno... and remember to style the button :)

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you! What's the difference between textContent and innerText?

Comment: Your welcome, glad to help... 

I usually use textContent as it's stated to be generally faster and should support almost every "nowadays used browser"...

However, there might be scenarios where you might wanna use innerText due to special requirements or for example functions, where you just want to return visible text.

I'd like to link [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213147/difference-between-textcontent-vs-innertext) for further details :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe mixing old-timey HTML with modern JavaScript is a disservice to both. Why not keep both modern?

See [Why are inline event handler attributes a bad idea in modern semantic HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11737873/215552), among others.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="module">
    function changeWords() {
      document.querySelector('#words').textContent = 'Words Have Been Changed';
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      document.querySelector('#change').addEventListener('click', changeWords);
    });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <p id="words">Starting Text</p>
    <button type="button" id="change">Change Words</button>

  </body>

</html>
```