How do I check the value inside an HTML element and use it in an if statement
So, I am trying to check the value inside an HTML element and use it as a conditional in an if statement in Javascript/TypeScript.
I am trying to do the following: if the element contains "-", you can stop playing, else, click the button and proceed with the game.
I initially created a variable where I could store the element
 const gameButton: string = '#GameButton';

Then I created an if statement where I used gameButton inside the conditional:
if (gameButton.includes("-") {
 console.log("Stop the game")
} else {
console.log("Click button to continue")
}

What is happening is that regardless of the value inside the button, I am still getting the "Click button to continue" message on console each time. What is the correct way of doing this?

Currently you are just checking the static string '#GameButton'. To get the value out of an HMTL element, first you need to get the information about the element with the document.getElementById() browser API. The returned object has a innerText property which holds the text displayed inside the element. Demo:


if (document.getElementById('GameButton').innerText.includes("-")) {
 console.log("Stop the game")
} else {
console.log("Click button to continue")
}
<button id="GameButton">Some-Text</button>




You need to first get the content of the element and then check if it contains the specified character. You can use document.querySelector for example


const gameButtonElement = document.querySelector('#GameButton');

if (gameButtonElement) {
    // Retrieve the text content of the button
    const buttonText = gameButtonElement.textContent || gameButtonElement.innerText;

    if (buttonText.includes("-")) {
        console.log("Stop the game");
    } else {
        console.log("Click button to continue");
    }
} else {
    console.log("Game button not found");
}
<button id="GameButton">Hello-World</button>




I didn't make this code with AI but it's a standard solution for this problem, anyways

@Yogi There's nothing in this code for IE8 compatibility. IE8 doesn't have document.querySelector() or String.prototype.includes().

But why do you think you need to check both textContent and innerText. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213147/difference-between-textcontent-vs-innertext
