# call a function inside innerHTML

Tags: javascript, loops, innerhtml

I need to call a function inside innerHTML and this is my try but it doesn't work.

```
category.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    docs.forEach(function(d) {
          var id = d._id
          document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += '<li onclick=insert(id)>' + d.name + '</li>'
    })
})

function insert(id){
  alert(id + "Inserted")
}
```

Here is the HTML Part:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Is `d._id` a number?

Comment: try this :  `'<li onclick=\'insert("' + id + '")\'>' + d.name + '</li>'`

Comment: @ A. El-zahaby your code also work, thanks ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variables in `onclick` attributes are evaluated in the global scope, you can't refer to local variables. You need to replace `id` in the string with the actual value of the `id` variable. You can do this with a template literal.

```js
const docs = [{
  id: "FgrbV2NTp72ie6xj",
  name: "Joe"
}, {
  id: "agfadsfasdfq23",
  name: "Fred"
}];

docs.forEach(function(d) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML += `<li onclick="insert('${d.id}')">${d.name}</li>`
});

function insert(id) {
  alert(id + " Inserted")
}
```

```html
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

Comment: It gave me undefined

Comment: It works in my snippet, you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: What datatype is `d.id`? If it's a string you'll need to quote it.

Comment: sorry it work on log: Uncaught ReferenceError: FgrbV2NTp72ie6xj is not defined
    at HTMLLIElement.onclick (index.html:1)

Comment: My original code assumed that `id` was a number, not a string, but I fixed it.

Comment: Yes, I just copy it as it is

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: the problem was _id instead of id

Answer (score 0):

```js
const docs = [{
  id: "FgrbV2NTp72ie6xj",
  name: "Joe"
}, {
  id: "agfadsfasdfq23",
  name: "Fred"
}];
let d = document;
d.g = d.getElementById;
let res = d.g('result');

let fragment = new DocumentFragment();
let el = null;
docs.forEach(function(item) {
  el = document.createElement('li');
  el.innerText = `${item.name}`;
  el.onclick = function(){
     alert(`${item.id}` + " Inserted");
  };
  fragment.appendChild(el);
});

res.appendChild(fragment);
```

```css
ul{
cursor:default;
}
```

```html
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

While `innerHTML` is easy to use, according to a discussant [here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945659/using-innerhtml-and-what-are-security-concerns?noredirect=1&lq=1):

> ...in general, .innerHTML is for small fragments of HTML to be
>   inserted and parsed into a document ..

So, instead of solving the OP's query with respect to `innerHTML`, this solution purposefully avoids it by utilizing DOM manipulation and at the same time makes the desired function available as a handler for an onclick event of an <LI> element.  To achieve this end, the code creates a [document fragment object](https://coderwall.com/p/o9ws2g/why-you-should-always-append-dom-elements-using-documentfragments).  As a result the code is able to add the LI elements as well as the id of each one and set the onclick event-property of each in a function invoked by the `docs.forEach()`.   Also, I added some CSS to enhance the cursor when user clicks "Joe" or "Fred".