# Whats the differecne between innerHTML and document.createTextNode

Tags: javascript, dom

So I wrote a simple form input that takes in a name and then displays it in a list below using li.innerHTML = "". I want to know would there be any difference if I used 
  li.appendChild(document.createTexNode("blabla"));

```
const form = document.querySelector("#myForm");
const btn = document.querySelector("#submitBtn");
const name = document.querySelector("#nameInput");
const msg = document.querySelector(".msgBox");
const namesList = document.querySelector("#userList");

var i = 1;

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (name.value === "")
    {
        msg.innerHTML = "Please enter a name!";
        setTimeout(() => msg.remove(), 2000);
    } else {
        const li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = name.value;
        namesList.appendChild(li);
        name.value = "";
    }
})
```

HTML file (if needed)

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>My Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Unesite ime</h1>
    <div class="msgBox"></div>
    <form id="myForm">
      <input id="nameInput" type="text">
      <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <ol id="userList"></ol>
  </body>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122760/is-there-any-major-difference-between-innerhtml-and-using-createtextnode-to-fill

Comment: `innerHTML` is a property of a Node ... `document.createTexNode` creates a text node ... they are totally unrelated

Answer (score 1):

`document.createTextNode` Creates a new Text node. This method can be used to escape HTML characters whereas `innerHTML` is used to get or set the HTML content of an element node.

If you like to update something with `html` then `innerHTML` do the job for you otherwise `document.createTextNode` is the safer function.